# How to use TOR along with the proxy

Tags: vpn, proxy

In a hypothetical network, one has to connect through a proxy to use the internet. However, via the this particular proxy only few websites are accessible and the rest get redirected to a page with a restriction message.

The proxy server is a HTTP Proxy hosted internally with a private IP. I wish to install a VPN service (eg. TOR) which can tunnel through this particular proxy. I am using Windows machine.

Comment: Fyi: bypassing Internet restrictions may be illegal and is likely against company/school policy

Answer (score 1):

Download [TOR Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/) and install it on your machine.

Open the TOR Browser and select "Configure". Here you can configure TOR to authenticate on your proxy server.

Comment: you mean to say all my data flows like this system -> tor -> proxy -> tor exit node ->internet

Comment: No, rather System -> Proxy -> TOR -> TOR Exit Node -> Internet.. Also enable  obfuscation of TOR traffic.

Comment: well will that setup work even if my proxy is a private ip

Comment: Yes. The traffic is routed first to the proxy in your network and from there to the TOR entry node or bridge.

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive guide can be found [here](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnel_Tor_through_proxy_or_VPN_or_SSH). Tor is not a VPN service as its means of operation and intended use are different; VPN has not been designed with sender anonymity in mind.

You cannot use the http protocol with Tor as Tor doesn't understand http. You will most likely need a SOCKSv4/5 server that accepts raw traffic as your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on the mechanism of the site list restriction. If it's implemented on HTTPS CONNECT level - then it's a big probability of the fail. If you can reach the websites served by Amazon Cloudflare and/or Azure - you can try to use meek-azure and meek-amazon pluggable transports.